# DJANGO: Get a parent queryset from a child queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

Say I have the following for my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Department(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department, related_name="department_users", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
```

So I am doing a lot of complex filtering on my User queryset to get to a subset of Users who are considered "active" but now I need to generate a list of Departments who have at least one "active" user.

I know that I can use a reverse lookup like: `Department.objects.filter(department_users__name__contains=...)` etc and do the filtering all over again but I wanted to know if there was a way to get that information directly from the "active" User queryset.

I tried using `.values()` but that gives me a queryset of dictionaries and I really wanted a queryset of django Models so I can do further filtering for the Department queryset.

Do you guys know if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a queryset of `User`s, you can load the `user`s and query the departments with:

```
Department.objects.filter(department_users__in=list(queryset_of_users)).distinct()
```

you can also do this without materializing the list of users with:

```
Department.objects.filter(department_users__in=queryset_of_users).distinct()
```

here your `queryset_of_users` will be a subquery, but that means that the database will do the work to determine the active users a second time.

The `.distinct()` clause will prevent returning the `Department` as many times as there are `User`s in the `queryset_of_users` for that department.

Comment: I think that way may be less efficient than just going the reverse-lookup path because you are cross referencing two lists of objects, it seems like there is no way to avoid doing all the filtering for departments aswell.

Comment: @LuizF.Bianchi: by calling `list(...)` you force the `queryset_of_users` to evaluate, and it will cache the users. if you thus later in the program iterate over the `queryset_of_users` it will not make the second query. The idea is that a queryset will only evaluate once. Of course if you construct a new queryset (for example by calling `.filter(...)` on the `queryset_of_users`, it ill again create a new queryset that will have to be evalauted.

Comment: @LuizF.Bianchi: in other words, by forcing evaluation of the first `list(queryset_of_users)`, you will prevent evaluating it a second time when you enumerate over the `queryset_of_users`.

Comment: I agree with you on that front but doing the "__in" lookup is also pretty demanding.

Comment: @LuizF.Bianchi: it will pass a list of primary keys, so the query will be `WHERE user.id IN (1,4,7, 15)` for example. You can work with `.distinct()` to prevent calling the query for the same department multiple times.